# Como navegar entre páginas no windows phone 8.1 usando mvvmcross?

Tags: c#, windows-phone, xamarin

Estou navegando entre páginas no Windows Phone 8.1 usando a seguinte chamada:

```cs
ShowViewModel<DetalheViewModel>();
```

Quando clico no botão *voltar* o app fecha. Como implemento a funcionalidade de voltar do botão?

Comment: Rafael, você esta utilizando Windows Phone 8.1 XAML Apps ou Silverlight apps?

Comment: XAML Apps com mvvmcross

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O ideal seria criar uma classe chamada BaseView (ou algo do gênero) que estenda a MvxWindowsPage e herdar as suas views desta sua BaseView, e não da MvxWindowsPage.

Sua classe BaseView seria mais ou menos assim:

```
public class BaseView : MvxWindowsPage
{
    public BaseView()
    {
        HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
    }

    private void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, BackPressedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(Frame.CanGoBack)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            Frame.GoBack();
        }
    }
}
```

Você também poderia criar uma baseViewModel e colocar um command para isso (GoBackCommand) e, ao invés de chamar a Frame.GoBack(), chamar algo como isso:

```
var vm = ViewModel as MyBaseViewModel;
if (vm != null)
{
    e.Handled = true;
    vm.GoBackCommand.Execute(null);
}
```

Ambas as formas estão corretas e funcionam.

Comment: Isso na minha Classlibrary qual a referência para o HardwareButtons ? não consigo adicionar a referencia de Windows.Phone.UI

Comment: Não, isso no seu projeto Windows Phone mesmo. Views são específicas, então não entram na PCL.